# Airflow tasks set to a pool not queued in this pool

Tags: airflow, pool

Airflow tasks are not being queued to the correct pool.

Subdag tasks take all the running slots in the current pool, so I created a separate pool for the sub-dag tasks.

[image: imagen]

And then assigned this pool to the subdags

```py
brand_subdag_operator = SubDagOperator(
    task_id=brand_id,
    subdag=brand_subdag,
    pool='subdags_pool',
)
```

But these tasks keep being scheduled at the `default_pool` instead of the new `subdag_pool`.

I expected that If the pool for the task is set to `subdag_pool`, for the task to be queued at this pool.

[image: imagen]

Related to https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10443